# How to load a TIFF image in Conda Python through QGIS package

Tags: qgis, python

I installed QGIS package in the Python environment, but while I load a TIFF image, it always fails, and no error reported.

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QFileInfo
from qgis.core import *
from osgeo import gdal

if __name__ == '__main__':
    QgsApplication.setPrefixPath\
        ("D:/software/installdic2/Anaconda3/envs/py36/Library", True)
    qgs = QgsApplication([], False)
    qgs.initQgis()
    gdal.AllRegister()
    my_project = QgsProject()
    my_project.write("D:/qgistest/my_project.qgs")

    my_pro = QgsProject()
    my_pro.read("D:/qgistest/my_project.qgs")

    filename = "D:/qgistest/000E00N.tiff.tif"
    file_info = QFileInfo(filename)
    base_name = file_info.baseName()

    layer = QgsRasterLayer(filename, base_name)

    if not layer.isValid():
        print("Layer failed to load")
    print(1)
```